# The Poincaré inequality for $H_0^1(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following is the well known [Poincaré inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality#The_classical_Poincar.C3.A9_inequality) for $H_0^1(\Omega)$:

> Suppose that $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is bounded in some direction. Then there is a constant $C$ such that
>   $$
> \int_\Omega u^2\ dx\leq C\int_\Omega|Du|^2\ dx\quad \textrm{ for all   }\ \ \color{red}{u\in H_0^1(\Omega)}.
> $$

Here are my **questions**:

- Could anyone come up with an example that $f\in H^1(\Omega)\setminus H_0^1(\Omega)$?
- Is the statement above true if one replaces $H_0^1(\Omega)$ with $H^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but doesn't adding a constant to $u$ have the potential to make the left side arbitrarily large without altering the right?

Comment: @T.Bongers The function $u$ has to be zero on the boundary.

Comment: For the second question, consider e.g. a constant function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $u \equiv 1$. Then, $u \in H^1(\Omega) \setminus H_0^1(\Omega)$ and your inequality fails (as long as $\Omega \ne \emptyset$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ be any function, then $u + c \in H^1(\Omega) \setminus H^1_0(\Omega)$ (provided $\Omega$ is bounded)

And yes, you need the function in $H^1_0$ for this to work. The intuition is easy (picture one dimension): if you know how big the derivative is (how fast the function is growing), you can know more or less which level will the function reach after some point, *provided that you know where it started*.

So if $u(0) = 0$ and $u'(x) \le 1$, you can say "I know $u(1) = u(0) + \int_0^1 u'(x)dx \le 1$". If you don't know $u(0)$ though you can make no such assertion.

Now clearly this analogy is not perfect (there are different kinds of norms in play) but it boils down to this

Comment: "provided that you know where it started" and "ended" in the case when $\Omega=(0,1)$?

Comment: @Jack No, the point is that you can estimate where it ended provided that you know where it started :)